# Unable to add comments to a post using a ModelForm in Django

Tags: python, django

**views.py**

```
def postdetail(request,pk): # Single Post view.

    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    comment = post.comments.all()
    comment_count = comment.count()

    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
            content = request.POST['cMessage']

            if form.is_valid():
                print("Yes valid")
                form.instance.body = content
                new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
                print(new_comment)
                new_comment.post = post
                new_comment.user = request.user
                new_comment.save()
                return redirect('blog-home')
        else:

            form = CommentForm()

    context = {
        'comment_form': CommentForm,
        'post' : post,
        'comments': comment,
        'count': comment_count,
    }

    return render(request,'post/postdetail.html', context=context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment by {self.user} on {self.post}'
```

**forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['body']
```

**template**

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <!-- respond -->
    <div class="respond">
        <h3>Leave a Comment</h3>
            <!-- form -->
                <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset>

                    <div class="message group">
                        <label  for="cMessage">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <textarea name="cMessage"  id="cMessage" rows="10" cols="50" ></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>

                </fieldset>
                </form> <!-- Form End -->
    </div> 
{% endif %}
```

There is no error being displayed neither If I am adding a comment using the shell/through admin panel but if I am trying to add the comment dynamically through the form then the comment is not getting saved.
I have added only the form in the template.

Comment: can you paste the code of html file which contains ContactForm?

Comment: @SahilDesai I have added.

Comment: I think you forgot to pass name of function inside action parameter in form tag.

Comment: @SahilDesai what should I add inside the action parameter.

Comment: No need to pass anything in action parameter. Sorry, for inconvenience. But still working on your error.

Comment: You don't have an input field with the name _body_ in your HTML form. Change `name="cMessage"` to `name="body"` or use `{{ comment_form.body }}` instead of `textarea` element and it should work. Also, read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) in the docs.

Comment: @Borut But I am getting the content using **content = request.POST['cMessage']** and saving it using form.instace.body = content. Once it worked fine when I have changed auto_add_now to **default=timezone.now** but now again its not working.

Comment: The form is not valid, because body is missing and is required. The errors are not displayed, because you are not outputting them.

Comment: request.POST will contain your data. you can access data like request.POST['body']

Answer (score 1):

You have defined field `body` in your `CommentForm`. It's required in your form, because you didn't include `blank=True` argument in your model for this field. This means that when you POST request and check if form is valid with `form.is_valid()`, the form expects an element with a name `body` in the request. If it's not there, it will not validate and content won't be saved.

Make the following changes:

1. Change your view to

   ```
   ...
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
           new_comment.post = post
           new_comment.user = request.user
           new_comment.save()
           return redirect('blog-home')
       else:
           print(form.errors) # or log it to a file, if you have logging set up

   form = CommentForm()
   ...
   ```
2. Change your HTML to this:

   ```
   ...
   <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <fieldset>
           <div class="message group">
               <label  for="body">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
               <textarea name="body" id="cMessage" rows="10" cols="50" ></textarea>
               {{ comment_form.body.errors }}
           </div>
           <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
       </fieldset>
   </form>
   ...
   ```

Comment: I tried making the following changes and when I am hitting the submit button it's giving the following error. **RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /post-detail/6
Comment has no user**

Comment: You didn't delete the rest of your code in the view, right? You still have `if request.user.is_authenticated` in your code? And check what you have in the blog-home view, because it could be that error is triggered when the code redirects.

Comment: Yes I haven't deleted my rest of the code and they are still the same I have just make the necessary changes as suggested by You and after that, it just shows the error(above mentioned). I checked by removing the redirect line but still, the same error is showing.

Comment: This error isn't related to this part of the code. Check the database and comments table if all your comments have user_id and if they do and the code you are showing here is real, run `makemigrations` and `migrate`, because considering your model it shouldn't be possible to save a comment without a `user`. Maybe your model used to be different and was allowing you to save a comment without a user.

Answer (score 1):

In views.py

```
def postdetail(request):
    print(Comment.objects.all())

    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
            content = request.POST['body']

            if form.is_valid():
                print("Yes valid")
                new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
                print(new_comment)
                new_comment.post = post
                new_comment.user = request.user
                new_comment.save()
                return redirect('blog-home')
        else:
            form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'temp/postdetail.html', context=context)
```

In html file

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="respond">
        <h3>Leave a Comment</h3>
        <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <textarea name="body"cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: The solution you have given above is working fine but I want to use the designed input field and not the Django's default widget.

Comment: try providing textarea with name=body

Comment: @SahilDeasi No, it's showing an error after submitting the form. **RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /post-detail/6
Comment has no user.**

Comment: @SugataKar From debug statements can you tell due to which line of code error occured.

Comment: **File "/home/sugata/Django-Work/Projects/blog/post/models.py", line 51, in __str__
    return f'Comment by {self.user} on {self.post}'**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214530/discussion-between-sugata-kar-and-sahildesai).